# How to bundle stylesheets

Tags: css, bundle, lumino

I have a stylesheet which has some imports from `node_modules`, and imported files may have even deeper imports, e.g.:

**src/style.css**

```
@import '@lumino/default-theme/style/index.css';
```

**node_modules/@lumino/default-theme/style/index.css**

```
/* ... */
@import '@lumino/dragdrop/style/index.css';
@import '@lumino/widgets/style/index.css';
@import './accordionpanel.css';
@import './commandpalette.css';
@import './datagrid.css';
...
etc. etc.
```

I need to somehow build/bundle such stylesheet into a single CSS file, to be able to include it in my HTML file, as I'm not exposing `node_modules` directly over HTTP(s). How to do that?

To be clear: it's question about bundling CSS and CSS only, not JavaScript.